# Is there any way to create new tabItem in TabControl WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I made a code in WinForm. It works.
I dragged xml file and dropped to tabPage.

```
        private TextEditorControl AddNewTextEditor(string title)
        {
            var tab = new TabPage(title);
            var editor = new TextEditorControl();
            editor.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            editor.IsReadOnly = false;
            editor.Document.DocumentChanged += 
                new DocumentEventHandler((sender, e) => { SetModifiedFlag(editor, true); });
            // When a tab page gets the focus, move the focus to the editor control
            // instead when it gets the Enter (focus) event. I use BeginInvoke 
            // because changing the focus directly in the Enter handler doesn't 
            // work.
            tab.Enter +=
                new EventHandler((sender, e) => { 
                    var page = ((TabPage)sender);
                    page.BeginInvoke(new Action<TabPage>(p => p.Controls[0].Focus()), page);
                });
            tab.Controls.Add(editor);
            fileTabs.Controls.Add(tab);

            if (_editorSettings == null) {
                _editorSettings = editor.TextEditorProperties;
                OnSettingsChanged();
            } else
                editor.TextEditorProperties = _editorSettings;
            return editor;
        }
```

But WPF is a bit dirrenet. 
Can I change the code for WPF?? or other way..? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

Suppose you have this `TabControl` with `TabItem` **A** and **B** and a `Button` for adding `TabItem`

```
<StackPanel>
    <TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
        <TabItem Header="A"/>
        <TabItem Header="B"/>
    </TabControl>
    <Button Content="Add New Tab Item" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
</StackPanel>

private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tabItem = new TabItem { Header = "C" };
    TabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);
}
```

After clicking the button you will be added **another TabItem (C)**